# Problem during installation - Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, software-installation

I'm installing Ubuntu 12.04 but I had this error :

An error occurred while installing packages:

```
"Command
'['debconf-apt-progress','--','apt-get','-y','install','user-first-login-u1','poppler-data',...............................
```

I still quote the message appears ..

```
This may be  due to using an old image , or it may be due to a bug in
some of the packages listed above. More details may be found in
var/log/syslog.The installer will try to continue anyway, but may fail
at later point,and will not be able to install or remove other
packages (possibly including itself)from the installed system. You
should look for newer versions of your installer image, or failing
that report the problem to your distributor.
```

So what should I do?

Comment: I'm installing it by default because it's the default OS with the new laptop .. what should I do ?

Comment: Is this pre-installed or something then? You may want to try a another installer from [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop). Could be a bit clearer as to what the problem is?

Comment: It is pre-installed on the laptop .. the problem occurs in installing packages on starting the computer for the 1st time ..

Answer (score 1):

For a preinstalled Ubuntu distro, you ought to try an contact the supplier about the problem, as they should of set it up so it works for you. They will probably help with problems like this until a year or so after the purchase - though it depends on the supplier.

Otherwise, just download and install the Ubuntu 12.04 installer [from here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop), burn it to DVD, or put it on a memory stick - instructions can be found [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-desktop-long-term-support) - and install it *(probably a wipe install if there is no important data on the machine)*. The end Ubuntu should be the same, though it may lack any pre-installed apps. You still might want to contact the supplier first.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like corrupted installation image. Maybe you can redownload it?

But anyways, I would suggest that you try with 13.10 as it is newer. 12.04 is almost 2 years old and that is a lot in Linux world.

Comment: 12.04 is still supported, and will be until 2017, so it should work mostly the same as an 13.10 install. See [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases).

Comment: @Wilf Of course it is, but I assumed that this user is a beginner in Ubuntu world, so it would benefit to him that he tries out newer version. Especially if he has problems with 12.04

Comment: I'm installing it by default because it's the default OS with the new laptop .. what should I do ?